# Why does Robert Jordan repeat ad nauseam that 'thinking is dangerous?'

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

Midway through his novel The Eye of the World, the first book in the saga, The Wheel of Time, Robert Jordan writes:

> He tried tracing the maze with his eyes, to see how many connections Ba'alzamon needed before reaching him, then gave it up as useless. Distances were deceiving here, another lesson he had learned. What seemed far away might be reached by turning a corner; what appeared close might be out of reach altogether. The only thing to do, as it had been from the beginning, was to keep moving. Keep moving, and not think. Thinking was dangerous, he knew.

> ....

> There had been two or three close brushes, though he could not remember them clearly, but for a long, long time - how long? - he had run while Ba'alzamon vainly pursued. Was this like Baerlon, or was it only a dream like other men's dreams? For an instant, then - just for the length of time it took to take a breath - he knew why it was dangerous to think, what it was dangerous to think about. As it had  before, every time he allowed himself to think of what surrounded him as a dream, the air shimmered, clouding his eyes. It turned to jell, holding him, just for an instant.

> The gritty heat prickled his skin, and his throat had long since gone dry as he trotted den the thorn-hedge maze. How long has it been now? His sweat evaporated before it had a chance to bead, and his eyes burned. Overhead - and not too far overhead, at that - boiled furious, steely clouds streaked with black, but not a breath stirred in the maze. For a moment, he thought it had been different, but the thought evaporated in the heat. He had been here a long time. It was dangerous to think, he knew that.

> ...

> This was a dangerous place, he knew that too. Ahead of him he could see three openings in the high wall of thorns, then the way curved out of sight. Ba'alzamon could be approaching any one of those corners at that very moment. There had been two or three encounters already, though he could not remember much beyond that they had happened and he had escaped - somehow. Dangerous to think too much.

> ...

> Abruptly he forgot the pain. His heel had overturned one of the smooth stones, kicked it out of the dry ground. He starred at it, and empty eye sockets stared back. A skull. A human skull. He looked along the pathway at all the smooth, pale stones, all exactly alike. He shifted his feet hastily, but he could not move without walking on the them, and he could not stay still without stepping on them. A stray thought took vague shape, that things may not be what they seemed, but he pushed it down ruthlessly. Thinking was dangerous, he knew.

I find this baffling as thinking is important. We don't just do it when we're actively thinking but even when we're thinking instinctively. So what does Robert Jordan mean by this? Could it have to do with his idea of what Buddism is about - after all, Jordan goes on about the void (even though there is no such concept in Buddhism)  Of course Buddhism does not deny thinking - there are plenty of books on Buddhist logic for example.

Comment: Did you not notice that all these references are in one chapter and one particular situation? I admit, it is not necessarily immediately obvious what the logical connection is, but I would think that it is obvious that it is not a general statement about the value of thoughtlessness.

Comment: That said, you include this phrase: "For an instant, then—just for the length of time it took to take a breath—he knew why it was dangerous to think, what it was dangerous to think about. As it had before, every time he allowed himself to think of what surrounded him as a dream, the air shimmered, clouding his eyes. It turned to jell, holding him. Just for an instant." That, of course, all but explains it even if you missed the plot of the chapter, so that does not precisely make me confident in the good faith behind this question....

Comment: Also, I was doing my best to assume good faith before, so I didn't want to assume that the quotation marks around 'novel' and 'saga', among other words in this and other questions, were meant as snide and unnecessary commentary on the quality of the work, so in the interest of preserving authorial intent, I did not edit them before. However, in light of the tract you wrote in the other question (now edited), I think that assumption should be revisited. I will edit them out, but feel free to revert if you disagree with my conclusion.

Comment: Have you been thinking about it? Has that thinking merely left you more confused than you were initially? There you go then.

Answer (score 2):

There is an in-universe reason explaining exactly why thinking is dangerous, in this very situation. It isn't explained until later in the books. Some fairly big spoilers ahead:

> When Ba'alzamon speaks to Rand and the others in their dreams, it is by invading their dreams through the world of Tel'aran'rhiod, a parallel dream world that all humans may sometimes visit randomly when they dream. Everything that happens there happens for real, possibly with lasting consequences when you wake up.
>
>  A stray thought in Tel'aran'rhiod could have fatal consequences. If you picture yourself in another place, or wearing other clothes etc, your surroundings might change to reflect your thoughts. In this scene, whoever is dreaming this (Rand?) seemed to have figured out this much.
>
>  To control your thoughts and your surroundings is therefore a fundamental skill for those who are consciously Dreamwalking - moving through Tel'aran'rhiod fully aware of how that world works.

Comment: Given who the dreamer is, it's also worth noting that this is probably _not_ that person's own conscious idea, but rather advice from "someone".